# Why is this simple update running so slowly?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm running what I thought was a fairly straight forward update on a fairly large table. I am trying to find out why this simple update is running so slowly. It took about 5 hours to complete.

`master` table: approx 2m row and 90 fields. 
`builder` table: approx 1.5m rows and 15 fields

I had initially attempted the insert directly:

```
-- Update master table with newly calculated mcap
update master as m
inner join 
  (select b.date_base, b.gvkey, sum(b.sec_cap) as sum_sec_mkt 
  from builder as b
  group by b.gvkey, b.date_base) as x
on  x.gvkey = m.gvkey AND 
    x.date_base = m.date_base
set m.mcap = x.sum_sec_mkt;
```

Unfortunately this ran for a number of hours and I finally killed it after waiting 4hrs.
I then thought I'd create a temporary table and insert the results from the initial select into it.

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_mkt_cap` (
  `date_base` date NOT NULL,
  `gvkey` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mkt_cap` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- insert market cap values in to temporary table
insert into temp_mkt_cap
select b.date_base, b.gvkey, sum(b.sec_cap) as sum_sec_mkt 
from builder as b
group by b.gvkey, b.date_base;

ALTER TABLE temp_mkt_cap
add primary key (date_base, gvkey);
```

The insert worked fine with `temp_mkt_cap` having about 1.4m rows, but the final update took 5hrs to complete.

```
-- Update master table with newly calculated mcap
update master as m
inner join temp_mkt_cap as mc
on m.date_base = mc.date_base AND m.gvkey = mc.gvkey
set m.mcap = mc.mkt_cap;
```

'master' has 'date_base' and gvkey_iid as `PRIMARY KEYS` and gvkey as a `KEY`.
I have completed more complicated inserts and updates on the table before and can't work out why this isn't working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

**Update:** The keys on the master table are:

```
ALTER TABLE master
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (gvkey_iid,date_base),
  ADD  KEY date_offset (date_offset),
  ADD  KEY gvkey (gvkey),
  ADD  KEY iid (iid);
```

**Update** I added a new key to the master table and the update ran in 93.6secs, down from 5 hours. Thanks for everyone's help.

```
ALTER TABLE master
  ADD KEY 'date-gvkey' (date_base, gvkey);
```

Comment: what are the keys on `temp_mkt_cap`?

Comment: @Sebas - after the insert I added date_base and gvkey as primary keys

Comment: do you need these single KEYs on date_offset, gvkey and iid? If I follow your queries, you only need your primary key. Same for temp_mkt_cap!

Comment: The best index you could have on table `builder` for this query would be either `(date_base, gvkey, sec_cap)` or `(gvkey, date_base, sec_cap)`. The grouping subquery would only use this index and not the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are joining on `mc.date_base AND m.gvkey = mc.gvkey`, you need an index on these fields in the same order you are joining them, on both tables.

If you are joining table1 with table2 `on table1.field1 = table2.field1 AND table1.field2 = table2.field2`, you need an index on `(table1.field1, table1.field2)` AND `(table2.field1, table2.field2)`.

`Not null` fields are preferable.

Also, because you are updating from the `mc.mkt_cap` field, you need a SINGLE key on this field if it is NOT already the first field of a composite key you created earlier.

ALL other keys or indexes are going to possibly slow down your query.

Please inspect carefully your database...

Comment: so despite date_base being part of the primary key and gvkey being a key in the master table, I need to create a new key with containing both there fields? Or would it be best to separate them into individual keys. I'm assuming temp_mkt_cap is fine since both date_base and gvkey are the primary keys? Sorry I'm fairly new to MySQL. I'll go do some more reading on keys. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are using fields together in joins, then yes there's a possibility that adding an index on the same fields in the same order, and setting them not null, would increase (up to drastically) the performances.

Comment: and no, the individual keys are not enough

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sebas, I left it running overnight and after about 6 hours if finished. I'll test it with by adding an index on date_base and see how it affects it.

Comment: I just ran it again after adding a new key to the master table (see update) and it ran in 93 seconds. Thanks again for your help.